# how to restore a trashed document in lotus domino in java

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I want to restore a trashed document in lotus domino.
On what basis we can know the parent view of a trashed document?
And how we can get all the items of the document back?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, Lotus Notes doesn't offer a way to do that via there API.

Soft deletes in Lotus Notes are explained here:  http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21091152

Also see [instructions on how to create a view that displays the soft deleted documents](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/dominowiki.nsf/dx/Create_a_Trash_view_equivalent_in_applications_without_a_Trash_view)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to know the parent view of a trashed document. The view decides what documents it contains based on the values in the document. Undeleting the document will cause it to appear in any views that should have it.

You can restore a document in Java by evaluating `@UndeleteDocument` in the context of that doc. The restored document will have all it's items as before.